# Not able to receive 3rd param from a website at localhost

Tags: php, yii, xampp, localhost

Following error is shown on the browser -

```
PHP notice

Undefined index: param3
```

Using firebug, found the following error -

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/app1/index.php?r=module/controller/action&param1=valueOFparam1&param2=valueOFparam2"
```

I am accessing 3rd param using

```
$param3= $_REQUEST["param3"];
```

in the controller. The website from which I am getting this URL sends three parameters in the URL but I am receiving only two at localhost.

Do I need to change anything in php.ini or anyhwhere else. I am using XAMPP server on Windows 7.

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: It looks like `param3` might not be set anywhere - it doesn't look like it's there in the URL.

Comment: There's really not enough info here. But @FabianTamp is probably right. Look for misspellings and maybe post the code that sets these variables.

Comment: Don't use $_REQUEST, use $_GET or $_POST, and obviously your 3rd param isn't set. You found the error yourself, why asking here what is the error without pasting code?

Answer (score 2):

As the firebug shown in your URL the 3rd parameter is not set! You should look for the source where redirect or forward to your current url and see why the param3 is not set?

/app1/index.php?r=module/controller/action&**param1**=valueOFparam1&**param2**=valueOFparam2